# Just how does this bit of Javascript work

Tags: split.js

I one of my current projects I am using Split.js. Given the complexity of that project I find it necessary to take the original SplitJS code and fork it one of my own ES6 classes. The process has gone smoothly but this line

```
const defaultGutterStyleFn = (dim, gutSize) => ({ [dim]: `${gutSize}px` })
```

has got me stumped. I am guesssing that defaultGutterStyleFn returns a CSS rule that bears the form `{dim:NNpx}` where

- `dim` is probably a dimension (height, width etc)
- `gutSize` is a numeric value

However, I do not see how the code I have quoted above would possibly doing this. Perhaps I have stumbled upon a JS/ES feature that I don't know?

Comment: This function is just returning an object with a property defined by the function arguments.  What consuming code *does* with this result is outside the control of this function.  It's not really clear to me what specifically isn't clear about this one small function.

Comment: It looks like just a wrapper to return an object

Comment: Yes, I suspected an object. What is confusing me is the square brackets around dim. What purpose do they serve. I ran the original Split.js code in a simpler scenario and found that `defaultGutterStyleFn` returns  `{height:18px}`

Comment: @DroidOS: I'm sure there's a proper duplicate somewhere, but that's just the syntax for using a variable/value to define a property name on an object.

Comment: I found an answer in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

I was not aware of this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a different way to write this:

```js
function defaultGutterStyleFn(dim, gutSize) {
    const result = {};
    result[dim] = gutSize + 'px';
    return result;
}
```